# Perform External validation before sending to next signer

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to send an Envelope to someone, have them fill it out and sign, do external validation, and then send the envelope to the next signer? Currently using the API, if I specify only one recipient, the Envelope is marked completed, and if I specify multiple recipients, the next signer is immediately notified after the previous person signs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a special recipient that is your "validator."
That recipient can be your system and using DocuSign Connect webhook, your system would be notified when it's your turn, between the first and third recipients. You can do the validation and decide how to proceed. You can do things like void the envelope or correct it. If you need the envelope to be routed differently - you can do that too.
The second recipient is just a mock one to stop the envelope from going to the next recipient upon signing of the first one.

Comment: Sounds like I may just have to do this. Can I set the form for the validator to do nothing besides approve/deny? I.e. they don’t edit anything at all?

Comment: you can make that recipient "need to view". Nothing to actually sign.